# Do separate tickets satisfy the UK's DATV transit requirement for an onward ticket?

Tags: visas, uk, transit, paperwork, transit-visas

I'm trying to travel to Nassau, Bahamas from Colombo, Sri Lanka with 1 connection in London Heathrow.

I am concerned about the "onward" ticket requirement in the DATV transit visa requirement. I think they will not grant it if I am on 2 separate tickets.

I can't seem to get it all on one itinerary. I can see there are flights in February on flightconnections.com but when I searched google flights and ITA, I can't find that route on a single itinerary. I would rather not use a travel agent.

Is this a concern? Is it important to book as a single itinerary?

Comment: it might be better to ask if two separate tickets satisfy the "onward" ticket requirement. It is my experience with other countries that nobody asked if it was one ticket or not.

Comment: I think it’s a bit more nuanced than that https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/939065/transit-guidance-v5.0ext.pdf#page7

Comment: Yes, does 2 separate tickets satisfy the onward ticket requirement?

Comment: @Traveller I read all six pages in there related to DATV and there was nothing at all about separate tickets vs single itinerary. The rules were more like "is that a sensible routing" and "do you think they actually intend to leave the airport instead of continuing their trip".

Comment: @Kate Gregory Yes, that’s what I meant to point out to the OP.

Comment: As both BA and Sri Lankan Airlines are one world airlines, the one world search tool has the best chance of finding any single tickets issued by the airlines. Since there do not seem to be any there a travel agent would appear to be to only option to get a single itinerary.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue won't be the UK embassy, but the airline. With separate tickets, check-in companies usually won't consider you an airside transit passenger, the main reason being you're not "insured" if anything goes wrong with the connection, leaving you stuck in the transit area. As such, they'll most likely deny boarding on the flight to the UK.

While the relevant UK government guidance says DATV holders may be allowed to cross the border in case of disruptions, this is internal guidance for UK officers and hardly for airlines, who instead tend to follow the blanket policy that transit on separate tickets isn't transit.

In your place, I'd get a Visitor in Transit visa, which lets you cross the UK border and stay for max 48 hours. With this, you should have no problems boarding your flight.

Comment: I feel that the DATV has more chance of approval than a Visitor in Transit. The problem is the 2 passengers are unemployed, single, and 30+.

Comment: @zwdev2 The difference isn't huge, but if you want, contact the handling agent for the relevant airline at Colombo airport (perhaps visiting the airport would be easiest), and ask if they'd let you board with a UK DATV if having separate tickets. No point in getting a visa if you're not getting on the plane.